# next js react app undefined compilation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am testing out a simple next.js react app, although an error is showing up when I try to access it at localhost:300. On line 46 of my news.js page, I am trying to test if state.articles is empty then copy props to it, although next.js is telling me .length is undefined. Does anyone know why .length is undefined?

Error is as follows; TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

any help is apprecaited

```
// This is the Link API
import Link from 'next/link';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
//import SearchForm from './components/SearchForm';

const apiKey = 'API-KEY';

const source = 'the-irish-times';

//build the url which will be sued to get the data
const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines? 
country=ie&category=sports&apiKey=${apiKey}`;


//getNews(url) is an async method which fetchs and 
returns data or and erroe
//from WWW Api
async function getNews(url){
//try fetch and catch any errors
try{
//make async call
const res = await fetch(url);
//get json data when it arrives
const data = await res.json();
//return json data
return(data);

  } catch (error){
return(error);
 }
}

// the news page definied as an ES6 Class
export default class News extends React.Component{
//constructor
//receive props and initialise state properties
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
  newsSource: "",
  url: "",
  atricles: []
  }
  } // end constructor
// render() method generates the page
render() {
//if state.articles is empty copy props to it
 **** THIS LINE
if(this.state.articles.length == 0){
  this.state.articles = this.props.articles;
}
return (
  <div>
    { /* display a title based on source */}
    <h3>{this.state.newsSource.split("-").join(" ")} 
</h3>
    <div>
    { /*iterate through artiles using array map */}
    { /* display author, publishedAT, image, desc and 
content */}
    { /* for each story also a link for more */}
    {this.state.articles.map((article, index) => (
      <section key = {index}>
    <h3>{article.title}</h3>
      <p className="author">{article.author} 
{article.publishedAt}</p>
      <img src={article.urlToImage} alt="artile 
image" className="img-article"></img>
      <p>{article.description}</p>
      <p>{article.content}</p>
      <p><Link href="/story"> <a>Read mor</a> </Link> 
</p>
      <p onClick = {this.test}>click..</p>
      </section>
    ))}
    </div>

   <style jsx>{`
   section {
     width: 50%;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     background-color: rgb(240, 248, 255);
     padding: 1em;
     margin: 1em;
   }

   .author {
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 0.8em;
   }
   .img-article {
     max-width: 50%;
   }
   `}</style>
</div>

);
}//end render
}

//get initial data on server side using an AJAX call
// this will initialise the 'props' for the news page


async function getInitialProps(response){
//build the url which will be used to get the data
const initUrl = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top- 
headlines? 
sources=${defaultNewsSource}&apiKey=${apiKey}`;

//get news data from tje api url
const data = await getNews(initUrl);

//if the result contains an articles array then it is 
good so return articles
if(Array.isArray(data.articles)) {
return {
  articles: data.articles
}
}
// otherwise it contains an error, log and redirect 
to error page
else {
console.error(data)
 if(response) {
response.statusCode = 400
response.end(data.message);
}
}
} // end initial props
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

**1.) Mistyped state property name**

I believe you meant `articles` not `atricles`.

Should be

```
this.state = {
  newsSource: "",
  url: "",
  articles: []
}
```

not

```
this.state = {
  newsSource: "",
  url: "",
  atricles: []
}
```

**2.) Mutating immutable React state**

In React we change the state with `setState()`. Keep in mind this is an asynchronous action and since you're calling it in the render function it will likely not appear until the next render.

```
if(this.state.articles.length == 0){
  this.setState({ articles: this.props.articles });
}
```

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.articles.length == 0){
      return (<div>Articles has no length</div>);
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        Articles has a length.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Application/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I changed both error 1 and error 2 in my code and I am still seeing the same error unfortunately

Comment: regarding your 2nd comment, this statement is from my college notes: 'When the page is first loaded, data will be rendered server-side using the React getInitialProps() method. This is a static method which is called before News is instatiated. Its initial data (props) is used in the constructor.' does that change anything?

Comment: Hmm, it shouldnt. I updated my comment to include a runnable snippet of code which appears to work fine. Sorry i couldn't help.